About comparative degree
Are the following sentences grammatically correct?
Sentence1:

This book is not any more interesting than the one I read last week.

Sentence2:

This book is not interesting any more than the one I read last week.

I think sentence1 is strange and sentence2 is natural.
What do you think?
If both of them are grammatically correct, are their meanings the same?

Sentence 1 is the normal way that English speakers express this idea.
"any more" modifies "interesting". It is an adverbial phrase modifying the adjective "interesting". In English, we generally put adverbs that modify adjectives BEFORE the adjective. (And adjectives before the noun.) We say, "the very tall man", not "the man tall very", etc.

Sentence (1) is only strange because it would be more natural to say

This book is no more interesting than the one I read last week.

Sentence (2) would be more natural with a comma -

This book is not interesting, any more than the one I read last week [was].

Making a break in the middle of the sentence turns the comparison with last week's book into an afterthought.

The second sounds a bit awkward or unnatural; I think I'd prefer "no more than..." or better "just like the one I read last week" or "much like" for a vaguer comparison.
